# I need advice should I use select or threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, http-live-streaming

I'm building a live radio streamer, and I was wondering how I should handle multiple connections. Now from my experience select will block the audio from being streamed. It only plays 3 seconds then stops playing. I will provide an example of what I mean.

```
import socket, select

headers = """
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n
Content-Type: audio/mpeg\n
Connection: keep-alive\n
\n\n
"""
file="/path/to/file.mp3"
bufsize=4096 # actually have no idea what this should be but python-shout uses this amount
sock = socket.socket()
cons = list()
buf = 0
nbuf = 0

def runMe():
    cons.append(sock)
    file = open(file)
    nbuf = file.read(bufsize) # current buffer
    while True:
        buf = nbuf
        nbuf = file.read(bufsize)
        if len(buf) == 0:
           break
        rl, wl, xl = select.select(cons, [], [], 0.2)
        for s in rl:
            if s == sock:
                  con, addr = s.accept()
                  con.setblocking(0)
                  cons.append(con)
                  con.send(header)
             else:
                  data = s.recv(1024)
                  if not data:
                     s.close()
                     cons.remove(s)
                  else:
                     s.send(buf)
```

That is an example of how i'd use select. But, the song will not play all the way. But if I send outside the select loop it'll play but it'll die on a 2nd connection. Should I use threading?

Comment: would you like to control _output_ availability as well? `socket.send` is also an operation that could block your code

Comment: Also, unlikely this could be a complete working example.

Comment: Threading and select are two very different things. Most likely you would have to use both. Or alternatively you are using a framework like twisted (there others als well).

Comment: what do you mean by control output? This is only the basic of what I've already made. I thought about twisted but wanted to try from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That is an example of how i'd use select. But, the song will not play
>   all the way. But if I send outside the select loop it'll play but
>   it'll die on a 2nd connection. Should I use threading?

You can do it either way, but if your select-implementation isn't working properly it's because your code is incorrect, not because a select-based implementation isn't capable of doing the job -- and I don't think a multithreaded solution will be easier to get right than a select-based solution.

Regardless of which implementation you choose, one issue you're going to have to think about is timing/throughput.  Do you want your program to send out the audio data at approximately the same rate it is meant to be played back, or do you want to send out audio data as fast as the client is willing to read it, and leave it up to the client to read the data at the appropriate speed?  Keep in mind that each TCP stream's send-rate will be different, depending on how fast the client chooses to recv() the information, as well as on how well the network path between your server and the client performs.

The next problem to deal with after that is the problem of a slow client -- what do you want your program to do when one of the TCP connections is very slow, e.g. due to network congestion?  Right now your code just blindly calls send() on all sockets without checking the return value, which (given that the sockets are non-blocking) means that if a given socket's output-buffer is full, then some (probably many) bytes of the file will simply get dropped -- maybe that is okay for your purpose, I don't know.  Will the clients be able to make use of an mp3 data stream that has arbitrary sections missing?  I imagine that the person running that client will hear glitches, at best.

Implementation issues aside, if it was me I'd prefer the single-threaded/select() approach, simply because it will be easier to test and validate.  Either approach is going to take some doing to get right, but with a single thread, your program's behavior is much more deterministic -- either it works right or it doesn't, and running a given test will generally give the same result each time (assuming consistent network conditions).  In a multithreaded program, OTOH, the scheduling of the threads is non-deterministic, which makes it very easy to end up with a program that works correctly 99.99% of the time and then seriously malfunctions, but only once in a blue moon -- a situation that can be very difficult to debug, as you end up spending hours or days just reproducing the fault, let alone diagnosing and fixing it.

Comment: "your code just blindly calls send() on all sockets without checking the return value" I don't mean to sound ew your answer is great, just I didn't understand that part. By return value do you mean the recv? Unless I don't understand sockets completely which is most likely true. the recv data only is there because I needed a way to check if client disconnects. But the only thing the server should do is send the mp3 data to all connected browsers live. That is why it sends to everyone. I'm still not an expert at python so sorry if I sound ew. Just trying to get a better understanding.

Comment: I mean that when you call s.send(buf), you don't do anything with the value that send() returned (i.e. you don't do 'numBytesSent = s.send(buf)', and then take an appropriate action based on the value of numBytesSent).  Since you're using non-blocking sockets, it's quite likely that the send() call did not send all of the bytes you asked it to send, but you have no way of knowing how many bytes were actually sent unless you look at the return value.

Comment: I didn't know send() returns anything, you learn new stuff everyday.

Comment: figured it out , how I did the buffer was the issue. So, I used threading to store the song frame by frame into a list. Then, I sent it to the browser frame by frame.